# Database "flapping" in Meteor.js?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

As Abigail Watson explains in [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/8lKB47kSSgY/rfUkVUo6jH4J) google group discussion, database flapping is a phenomenon occurring in Meteor.js, but it's not elaborated upon. It seems that a [package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/event-hooks) has emerged to fix this problem.

So, my question is, what is "database flapping" in Meteor.js, and how does it affect me when checking e.g. Meteor.user() in Deps.autorun()?

EDIT: I added a code example that's giving me headache, and which I believe is caused by "database flapping". When a user logs in, the console.logs inside Meteor.user() is usually run a couple of times, the same with the logout console.logs. Inside 'userLoggedOut' I am resetting the Meteor.user().profile.setAvailable boolean, and sometimes this throws me into an eternal loop, because if(Meteor.user()) is then run again. This could of course be me doing something wrong as well.. :)

I have run into this problem when using this code:

```
var lastUserId;
Deps.autorun(function () {
    if(Meteor.user()) {
        lastUserId = Meteor.user()._id;
        console.log("USER LOGGED IN WITH USER ID", lastUserId);
        if (Meteor.user().profile.setAvailable) {
            Meteor.call('setAvailable',
            {
                options: Meteor.user()
                               .profile
                               .someDataThatShouldBeSetAvailable
            });
        }
        if (Meteor.user().profile.forceLogOut) {
            Meteor.call('resetForceLogOut',
                {
                    userId: Meteor.user()._id
                });
            window.location.reload();
        }
    } else {
        if (lastUserId) {
            console.log("LOGOUT: We should do something
                with this id", lastUserId);
            Meteor.call('userLoggedOut',
                {
                    userId: lastUserId
                });
        } else {
            console.log("We don't have any lastUserId, the page 
                has probably been refreshed");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Have you run into this issue? What are you trying to do? Your question would be easier to answer if you provided an expected result, an actual result, and some code to reproduce the actual result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known to happen because the user seems to be sent down in stages. Initially its `null`, then its basic (from the latency compensated `.setUserId`) then the actual data is received from the server. Each time the `Deps.autorun` will be re-run.

The way around it is to check for the profile so only the final run is caught

change this line

`if(Meteor.user()) {`

to this

`if(Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile && Meteor.user().profile.name`

Here its assuming you have a `.name` field in your `profile` but you could use any field. It could be anything else if you have it. The idea is to only wait for the last chunk of data concerning the user to arrive from the server.